# Netbeans groovy 1.8 support

Tags: grails, netbeans, groovy, netbeans-7

I am using NetBeans 7.1, which comes with Groovy 1.6 support. I have to do a Grails project, but with Groovy 1.8 support. So I downloaded Groovy 1.8 installer, installed it and added the Library in Netbeans -> Tools -> Libraries (and removed Groovy 1.6 library).
Now whenever I use some stuff added in Groovy 1.8 within my Grils project, it still underlines it and throws "cannot resolve" error... I was googling it for last 2 hours and everything I find seems I have already done... it starts to give me a headache... Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: See Blog entry at Mark's Area of Thoughts: http://www.areaofthoughts.com/2011/11/upgrading-groovy-in-netbeans-ide-71.html Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans support from Groovy has -- until recently -- stagnated.

The Groovy support (as you say) is for Groovy 1.6.X, and the Grails support is similarly old.

There has [very recently been some activity](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansgroovy/) in trying to improve this, but at the current time you are probably better using Eclipse, [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (both free) or [IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) (paid) if you want proper IDE support for up to date Grails development.

Comment: Thanks, like you advised I ditched NetBeans and got STS and everything works.

Comment: Worth having another look at NetBeans when 7.2 comes out, as there's definitely some movement in Grails development and bugfixes :-)

Comment: with respect to STS vs IntelliJ - my opinion here is that you definitely get what you pay for :)